# Is it possible to build a LAN with just Access Points?

Tags: switch, router, wireless, ieee-802.11, access-point

I am just learning the differences between routers and AP. Based on what I have understood, AP just acts like a wireless switch enabling multiple devices to connect to a single router.

Since it is possible to build a LAN with just a single switch, is it possible to build a LAN with single AP without internet access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Your wireless clients can communicate with each other (although on some consumer devices, you have to explicitly allow this).

Comment: This is known as ad-hoc mode, right?

Comment: @gardenhead No, this is still infrastructure mode.  Ad-hoc does not use an AP.

Answer (score 4):

A LAN is a layer-2 network, and all hosts on a LAN are peers. Routers route between networks, not from a LAN back to the same LAN. Switches and WAPs are bridges that operate on layer-2 LANs, and neither requires a router unless the hosts need to communicate to/from a different LAN.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Computers in this case are in the same network, and they can communicate with each other through the AP.

Comment: Why can't a server be on the wireless network?

Comment: Here we assumed there is no internet access , the AP acts like a switch so the devices connected to the AP can communicate without access the Internet

Comment: I'm talking about local servers on the WLAN. Obviously you can't reach Internet servers if you're not connected to the Internet.

Comment: you can reach server in the same network

Comment: You should clarify the answer to say what you really mean. Although I don't understand the point you were trying to make -- it's obvious that he's talking about a local network that's not connect to the Internet, so why would anyone think you could connect to Internet servers?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify why computers are peers